# Setar model in r

Tags: r, threshold

I am currently working on a threshold model using Tsay approach. I am really stuck on how to determine the Threshold value and I am currently using R.
From the book I read I noticed firstly I need to create a scatter plot of recursive t ratios of AR cofficients vs ordered threshold, inorder to identify the threshold value. However I'm not able to produce this plot in R.
Is there R codes available to generate this plot?

Comment: Closevote for lack of programming specific material .... like code and data. SO is not a "write a complete example for me" server. Could possibly have been an acceptable question on CrossValidated, but even that forum has standards for the level of description of a problem. They also don't like language-specific questions, Suggestion: read [ask] and [MCVE]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.